# How to create plugin?

Tags: jquery, dart

I know how to create plugin in **jQuery**

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.pluginName = function(options) {
        // Establish our default settings
        var settings = $.extend({
            opt1 : 'value',
            opt2 : null
        }, options);

        this.each( function() {
            // code
        });

    }

}(jQuery));
```

To invoke plugin just:

```
$('el1, el2').pluginName({ opt2: 'Hello World!' });
```

But, how create plugin in **dart**?

Shoud I create class and to constructor add selector and options?

```
class PluginName {
    String selector;
    String opt1;
    String opt2;

    PluginName( selector, { this.opt1: 'value', this.opt2: null } ) {
        queryAll(selector).forEach((element) {
            // code
        });
    }
}
```

And then invoke like:

```
new PluginName('el1, el2', { opt2: 'Hello World!' });
```

Or is there better way how to create dart plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise using the [WebUI library](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/) for plugin development. WebUI allows you to build modular components that contain their own content (HTML), style (CSS), and logic (Dart). You should generally not need to pass in selectors, since the component should know everything it needs too about its markup. Here is a brief example of a component that takes will shrink it's text on mouse over and regrow on mouse out:

**xshrinktext.html**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
      <body>
        <element name="x-shrink-text" constructor="ShrinkTextComponent" 
extends="div">
          <!-- Style the component -->
          <style>
            .shrunkText {
              font-size: 0.2em;
            }
          </style>


          <!-- Component content -->
          <template>
            <div on-mouse-over="shrink()" on-mouse-out="unshrink()">
              {{text}}
            </div>
          </template>


          <!-- Add logic -->
          <script type="application/dart">
            import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

            class ShrinkTextComponent extends WebComponent {
              String text;

              void shrink() {
                getShadowRoot('x-shrink-text').classes.add('shrunkText');
              }

              void unshrink() {
                getShadowRoot('x-shrink-text').classes.remove('shrunkText');
              }
            }
          </script>

        </element>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**Using the component:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="import" href="xshrinktext.html">
  </head>

  <body>
    <x-shrink-text text="Hello World!"></x-shrink-text>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Some notes:

- You don't have to call any code to create the plugin; all you need is the x-shrink-text tag
- The `{{text}}` syntax binds the value to the `String text` property declared in ShrinkTextComponent
- You can pass in default values when using the component: `<x-shrink-text text="Some other text!"></x-shrink-text>`
- `getShadowRoot()` will retrieve the root element of the component; no need to query the DOM
- You have to import the component in order to use it
- You can bind events directly to the DOM elements: `<div on-mouse-over="shrink()></div>`

As you can see, web components are a very powerful way of encapsulating and reusing application code and content. This is a brief example that only touched on the basics of web components, I encourage you to read more on the subject. The link I posted above is a good starting point.

Comment: nice, for web components is great, but what about toolip for all `<a>` or `a` with specific `class`. And its valid creating new elements/attributes in html and xhtml?

Comment: The point is that instead of using `<a>` and assigning it a class and then going through the DOM and altering them you would instead have something like `<x-tooltip-anchor>` wherever you would want it. Of course, if you want you can go through the DOM with queryAll, but personally I much prefer the web component route.

Comment: Using `<x-shrink-text>` is just for your own use. It will actually get converted to `<div is="x-shrink-text">` for the actual HTML.